# Rails equivalent for MapPath (from ASP.NET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does Rails have an equivalent of the Server.MapPath method from ASP.NET? I've tried looking for one, but couldn't find anything.

**Edit**: I need this to generate a PDF with some images stored on the server. I know the relative path (URL) of the images, but I need an absolute path on disk to load them. I use FPDF for this and even though it says it accepts an URL, it doesn't seem to be the case (or I couldn't make it work).

It checked that it works with a hardcoded physical disk path and now I need to make it flexible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Is .connect not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has one: [File.expand_path](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002563).
You can also use Rails.root to get the current path to rails project, then compose the path from there.

```
File.join(Rails.root, "public", "404.html")
File.expand_path("public/404.html", Rails.root)
```